# Making applications hosted on third machine available through RDP?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-server-2019, remoteapp

We have a RDP "jump box" which is the only machine on our local network allowed to get incoming RDP connections. Is there a way to make applications on another machine (not the jump box, but on the same network) available on the RDP-jump box without having the user create another RDP session?

Comment: I see you added the RemoteApp tag. Does that mean you tried it and it doesn't work for you?

Comment: I am currently unaware if RemoteApp can be used to access applications on machines that don't have RDP licensing set up. Is this the case?